# How to install ubuntu without a dvd?

Tags: installation, downloads

Recently I downloaded ubuntu 13.04 (iso). Now after extracting the iso file and running wubi - it says downloading required files though I had already downloaded the iso file (794 MB). So what to do now?

Comment: make bootable usb ...dual boot

Comment: Do not flag your own question when you simply need an answer, as it is a waste of moderator time and doesn't actually get you any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wubi in 13.04 is not in a releasable state. You have to install Ubuntu 12.10 through wubi and then upgrade to 13.04. follow this [steps](http://schoudhury.com/blog/articles/install-ubuntu-13-04-with-ubuntu-wubi-installer/)

Comment: is there any way to install it without using ubuntu 12.10

Comment: @user101535 i suggest you to burn a dvd or even better create a bootable usb stick(faster installation with the stick) and make a nice and clean installation of 13.04. I don't see the point in using wubi anymore, as the installation process is dead simple

Answer (score 1):

Use the ISO that you have downloaded. You can make a boot-able pendrive by using this utility at http://www.pendrivelinux.com/. Then you can install ubuntu using this pendrive.

PS. : in your boot options just check that USB is higher priority to the hard-drive.

Also, Wubi currently is not the best way of installing Ubuntu. You can read it for yourself [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/wubi-advice)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, or even on Wine you could also try Unetbootin or LinuxLiveUsb.

I tried both of those for the first time yesterday, both were remarkably easy to use and did the job perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT extract ISO files. Instead mount it using ISO mounting program, and run Wubi. I suggest use Wubi only when you using Ubuntu [12.10](/questions/tagged/12.10)

---

If you mean installing it on its own partition, instead use [live-usb](/questions/tagged/live-usb) from [pendrive](/questions/tagged/pendrive) using [UUI (Universal USB Installer)](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/).